# $n = \sum_i d_i = \sum_i d_i^{-1} \implies d_i = 1$

Tags: matrices, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a (non-zero) natural number and let $d_1 , \dots, d_n > 0$ positive real numbers. Assume that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n d_i = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i^{-1}= n.$$

Does it follow that $d_i = 1$ for all $i=1, 2, \dots, n?$

Context question: I want to prove that if $X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a positive and invertible matrix with $Tr(X) = Tr(X^{-1}) = n$, then $X=I_n$. By diagonalizing, I obtained the above condition on the diagonal entries so if the above is true I can conclude my proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n d_i = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i^{-1}= n\implies \sum_{i=1}^n d_i+d_i^{-1}= 2n
$$
Now simply use $$x+\frac{1}{x}\ge 2\quad,\quad x>0.$$

Comment: Thanks! Using that the inequality $x+x^{-1}\ge 2$ is strict when $x \ne 1$, I was able to conclude.

Comment: Good job. That's the remaining part of the proof.